# Is there a faster alternative than `nixos-rebuild switch` when updating services?

Tags: nixos, nix

Often I'm configuring a new service and having to run `nixos-rebuild switch` for the changes to take effect.

For example setting up a configuration for a webserver.

However the `nixos-rebuild switch` takes quite a few seconds to run.  Is there a quicker alternative to rebuild just a subset of my Nixos configuration? I did notice a `--fast` parameter - however this does not seem to make much of any difference.

Answer (score 0):

`nixos-rebuild test` - doesn't spend time in updating grub. Run `nixos-rebuild switch` or `nixos-rebuild boot` when configured to your heart's content

Comment: Is it possible to do nixos-rebuild without network access? Say all I want to do is a config change that shouldn't require any new packages.

Comment: I'm not certain but I believe you can clone the main nixpkgs repository from Github, and then whenever you do a `nixos-rebuild` you can point it at your local nixpkgs instead of the remote.  Explained in the manual here:  https://nixos.org/manual/nixos/stable/index.html#sec-custom-packages

Comment: @Philippe I believe recent versions have something of a no-internet switch (or is it coming with nix 2.4?) but I never got it working :}

Answer (score 0):

> If you only want to evaluate `configuration.nix` without building (e.g. to syntax-check or see if you are using module options correctly), you can use:
> `$ nix-instantiate '<nixpkgs/nixos>' -A system`

Taken from: https://nixos.wiki/wiki/Cheatsheet